# Should I have different APIs methods for different concrete classes?

Tags: api, design-patterns

I am writing an APIs for greeting cards.

A card contains just List of lines and Card ID. The card has method called Greeting.

A line is just set of characters.

I have an interface Card and several concrete classes  that implements this interface, i. e, ChristmasCard, EasterCard... etc.

I am writing an API method that returns the card by ID.

From design perspective, is it better to write single API method that returns any type of card based on the ID, or, its better to write an API for every card type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of questions have always the same answer which is: **It depends**, all the design patterns have trade offs and that's software engineering.

In general though my approach would be something like the following.
So having the `Card` being the abstraction and containing the `id` you should probably define the `findById` returning any type (meaning it will return the abstraction type, `Card`) because this operation is only using the `id` field which is agnostic to the derivatives of the `Card` class. In that way your API code is decoupled from the specific implementations of the `Card` interface. You can go a little more further by using generics if you want your code to be reused to other `Entities` who share the same logic.

If you write an API for every card type as you proposed then your API is coupled to the implementation so every new derivative added would affect your API as well (as you should probably add the new added type to your API).

**In general you want to depend on abstractions and not on implementation details**

Comment: thx @Alexis, what about the creation ? is it better to create a create method for every card ? or create one method for all cards ? ( given cards can have different parameters)

Comment: You should use a factory method pattern for that and delegate that responsibility to other class. You can create a factory method that takes as input a parameter (a string or an enum for example) and depending on the input (probably with a switch statement ) you will return the specific direvetive. (The return type should be `Card`)